# Website login not working with selenium/python?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on a project with Python that automates pricing updates on various websites for my company. I've hit a wall with this one website, which doesn't let me get through the login screen. The strange thing is I don't believe it's a problem with my code, as the same code has worked for 10 other websites without any issue. I don't think it's an incorrect user/pw either because when I manually enter an incorrect pw, the site gives me a red "Incorrect username or password."

However, once I run my Python code:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
username.send_keys("username")
pw = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
pw.send_keys("password")
pw.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

The login screen gives me the loading icon, and then just refreshes with no red text. Any ideas if this is a code or site issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your code makes an assumption that every site you visit requires a username/password and furthermore that the field IDs are always the same. Are you sure that's right?

Comment: @BrutusForcus those are the xpaths directly from the login page on the site. I've tried ID & css selector but still the same issue.